# Get context of an object

Tags: python, oop, python-3.x, introspection

I'm writing a game in Python. The player character and enemy characters are instances of `Person`. Characters can have powers, of class `Power`. When a character uses a power in combat, the `Power` object needs to know who owns the power (in order to apply whatever effect the power has). How can I let the `Power` object know who its `Person` is?

One obvious solution is to include a creation argument storing a reference to the `Person`. However, this has several issues; one is that any methods of `Power` will likely then also need access to that variable, which gets awkward as I'm already passing around a bunch of arguments to every method.

I'd rather have a sort of 'clever' solution that allows an object to look 'up' to see where it is. Is there something like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not clear exactly how your objects interact, but here is a minimal example of one option:

```
def Power():

    def use(self, person):
        # do whatever


def Person():

    def __init__(self, power):
        self.power = power

    def use_power(self):
        self.power.use(self)
```

This provides an interface to the `Power` in `Person`, and passes the `Person` explicitly to the `Power` when it is `use`d.

Comment: Ok, that's not a way that's occurred to me before. Very simple and clear, but also well-structured. Seems like the way to go...